# Clarity Design Systems - Vertical Nav

Tags: vertical-alignment

I was looking at the Vertical nav options on clarity. I would just like to know if its possible to right align the nav?

the example code I used on clarity is as follows:

```
<div class="main-container">
<header class="header">
    ...
</header>
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <clr-vertical-nav>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./charmander" routerLinkActive="active">Charmander</a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./jigglypuff" routerLinkActive="active">Jigglypuff</a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./pikachu" routerLinkActive="active">Pikachu</a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./raichu" routerLinkActive="active">Raichu</a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./snorlax" routerLinkActive="active">Snorlax</a>
        <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./credit" routerLinkActive="active">Credit</a>
    </clr-vertical-nav>
</div>
```

This works perfectly but aligns the nav to the left margin. Any advise on how to align it to the right margin?

Answer (score 1):

Clarity uses `flexbox order` property to align `side-nav` to left

[image]

> If you want to align `side-nav` to right change the `negative` order
>   to `positive number` Or `zero`

```
.sidenav{
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   order: 1;
}
```

or

```
.main-container .content-container .clr-vertical-nav, .main-container .content-container .sidenav {
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   order: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will give it a try.